# why the state of the code change without any function triggered

Tags: reactjs

I wrote this To do list componnet before and I just wrote through it today found that I realise I was just got lucky to make it through cause I cann't really figure out how does it even work.

The thing is I think when I use useState, it would give a global state so when I click an item, it would run the combined and depends on the state it would either go cross or delete.

But I just found out if multipule items are created the state should be true so when combined function is triggered it should go delete not cross but somehow the app works it would cross or delete depends on which item I clicked which is super weired.

I can't figure out why the state would automativecally change back to false even none of function is triggered. I alrealy put a lot of console.log trying to figure out when the state changed but still can't find out.

[when I clicked the second items, the state changed to false even before the combined function is trigged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1nc6.jpg)

```
import React from "react";

function ToDoItem(props) {
  console.log(clicked+'0');
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);
  console.log(clicked+'1');
  
  function cross() {
    setClicked((prevValue) => {
      return !prevValue;
      
    });
  }
  function deleting() {
    props.onChecked(props.id);
    console.log(clicked+"delete");
    setClicked((prevValue) => {
      return !prevValue;
    });
  }
  console.log(clicked+"middle");
  function combined() {
    console.log(clicked+"combinecheck");
    if (!clicked) {
      console.log(clicked+"cross");
      cross();
      console.log(clicked+"alreadycross");
    } else {
      console.log(clicked+"delete start");
      deleting();
      console.log(clicked+"alreadydelete");
    }
    
  }
  return (
    <div onClick={combined}>
      <li style={{ textDecoration: clicked ? "line-through" : "none" }}>
        {props.text}
      </li>
      {console.log(clicked+'dom')};
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToDoItem;
```

Comment: Why do you think that useState should be global? After all, the function is invoked inside the Todoitem function. That means that each item gets its own state.

Comment: Ahh, I'd never though of it, so if the state is passed down from the parrent, then it's gloabl?

Comment: Not necessarily: if the state is passed from the parent then it's scoped to that parent. If the parent is a kind of `TodoList` and it passes a state variable into its `TodoItem` children, then all children would "see" the same state and calling the setter function will modify the state for all other items, too. But directly passing state is a suboptimal design: better to emit an event from the child, then have the parent react and update the props of its children.

Comment: I see, it clicked when I read your comment. Cheers mate.